# cargar correctamente las variables de entorno de laravel en javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-8

Quisiera saber como se llaman correctamente las variables de entorno Laravel, La cuestión es la siguiente:

En javascript hago esto :

```
let variable = {{ env('APP_URL) }}
```

el navegador me muestra:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token:

Siempre me muestra esa linea en el depurador y con punto y coma o sin el me aparece siempre el mismo error y no puedo accceder a esta.

Tambien he intentado hacerlo asi:

```
let base_url = {{ config('app.url') }}
```

Siempre me muestra el mismo error, y aunque muestra la url que esta almacenada, no puedo trabajar con esta.

Version laravel **Laravel 9**

Comment: Las [variables de entorno](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_de_entorno) sólo pueden accederse dinámicamente en el servidor y no en el cliente. Javascript se ejecuta en el lado cliente. Existen diversas formas de "enviar" valores desde el servidor al cliente, pero intentar acceder a variables de entorno desde el cliente no es lo correcto ni adecuado. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @MauricioContreras.  Saludos